# Strange behavior of marker events in OpenLayer

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, openlayers, markers

I have markers layer on my map.

Every time I add a new marker I register it to a mouse-click event:

```
var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat);
var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat,icon);
marker.id = callId;

marker.events.register("mousedown", marker, function() {AddPopup(marker.id);});

callMarkers.addMarker(marker);
```

Sometimes I want to disable/enable the event. so I use these functions:

```
function EnableAllMarkers()
{ 
    for (var i in callMarkers.markers)
    {
        callMarkers.markers[i].events.remove("mousedown");               

        callMarkers.markers[i].events.register("mousedown", callMarkers.markers[i],   

        function() { AddPopup(callMarkers.markers[i].id); });
    }  
}


function DisableAllMarkers()
{ 
    for (var i in callMarkers.markers)
    {
        callMarkers.markers[i].events.remove("mousedown");
    }  
}
```

When I use this code I get strange behavior - sometimes a popup opens for the wrong marker.

I click on marker X and popup Y opens.

Can someone help me, please?

Note:
The reason `EnableAllmMarkers` first removes the event is because we don't know if `DisableAllmMarkers` was ever called since a new marker was added. if it was called indeed, remove function will do nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a classic JavaScript trap: you're instantiating functions as event handlers in a loop, and the functions refer to a local variable. The problem is that **all** of them refer to the **same** local variable: the same, single, unique, only-one-place-in-memory variable.  The variable in this case is "i".

At the end of that `for` loop, "i" will have the value of the last key in the object (and, by the way, if `callMarkers.markers` is really an array, then this shouldn't be a `for ... in` loop anyway, but that's a separate issue).  When those events finally fire, therefore, all the handlers will do their thing with "i" equal to that one same key.

To fix:

```
  for (var i in callMarkers.markers)
    {
        callMarkers.markers[i].events.remove("mousedown");               

        callMarkers.markers[i].events.register(
          "mousedown", 
          callMarkers.markers[i],
          (function(ii) {
            return function() {
              AddPopup(callMarkers.markers[ii].id);
            }
          )(i)
         );
    }
```

That introduces an intermediary anonymous function. That function is immediately called, and passed the current value of "i".  By doing that — passing "i" as an argument to the anonymous function — the value is "captured" in the argument "ii".  Each loop iteration will cause another invocation of the anonymous function, and the function it returns (the actual handler) will have access to its own private "ii" variable.

There are some other ways to achieve the same thing, but they're all just variations on this theme.

Comment: thank you, I'll check it. What did you mean in "separate issue"?

Comment: Ah - well, if you've got a real Array (indexed by integers), then you should use `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` instead of `for (var i in array)` - the latter way is risky because there may be other weird properties of the array object that you **don't** want to include in the iteration.

Comment: i tried with your suggested code but now, the event handler is called again and again without me clicking on the marker

Comment: Well, perhaps something else is wrong. The change I described here is an extremely common JavaScript technique, and it comes up in Stackoverflow questions all the time; there are probably hundreds of other questions like this.  The transformation I made only changes the handler functions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, once the event is registered to a specific Maker it triggers for all the other Marker's as well. Finally, I was able to solve it. I had to register seperate events for each marker. Following is my code:

```
    var makerCount=0; // I want only 2 Markers to be shown : Source,Destination

function setMarkers(x,y){
    var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png',size,offset);  

 if(makerCount<2){

    if(makerCount==0){  // Source
       var location = new OpenLayers.LonLat(x,y); 

       var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
       var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);

        var sourceMarker=new OpenLayers.Marker(location,icon)
        sourceMarker.events.register('mousedown', sourceMarker, function(evt) { 
                alert('Source :: X='+ x + ' , Y=' + y); 
                OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt); }); 


        markers.addMarker(sourceMarker); 
        markers.setOpacity(0.2);
        makerCount++;
    }else{ // Destination

        var location = new OpenLayers.LonLat(x,y); 

        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
        var halfIcon = icon.clone();  

        var destinationMarker=new OpenLayers.Marker(location,halfIcon)
        destinationMarker.events.register('mousedown', destinationMarker, function(evt) { 
                alert('Destination :: X='+ x + ' , Y=' + y); 
                OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt); 
           });          
        markers.addMarker(destinationMarker); 
        halfIcon.setOpacity(0.5);
        makerCount++;
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: If anyone is having the same problem. Simply using "icon.clone()" instead of "icon" fixed it for me.